# Adding Text and Value to ComboBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms

I have got following **WinForm** code from this link: http://net-informations.com/q/faq/combovalue.html

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim comboSource As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
    comboSource.Add("1", "Sunday")
    comboSource.Add("2", "Monday")
    comboSource.Add("3", "Tuesday")
    comboSource.Add("4", "Wednesday")
    comboSource.Add("5", "Thursday")
    comboSource.Add("6", "Friday")
    comboSource.Add("7", "Saturday")
    ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(comboSource, Nothing)
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Key"
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim key As String = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)).Key
    Dim value As String = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)).Value
    MessageBox.Show(key & "   " & value)
End Sub
End Class
```

I have tried to convert above **WinForm** codes to **WPF** codes like following.

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Height="25" Width="100" Content="Click Me"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1" Height="25" Width="200"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

code behind

```
Class MainWindow
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Dim comboSource As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
    comboSource.Add("1", "Sunday")
    comboSource.Add("2", "Monday")
    comboSource.Add("3", "Tuesday")
    comboSource.Add("4", "Wednesday")
    comboSource.Add("5", "Thursday")
    comboSource.Add("6", "Friday")
    comboSource.Add("7", "Saturday")
    ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(comboSource, Nothing)
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Key"
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim key As String = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)).Key
    Dim value As String = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)).Value
    MessageBox.Show(key & "   " & value)
End Sub
End Class
```

But I come across some errors as you can see in this picture: https://prnt.sc/na5iie

So, how can I solve that errors?

Comment: Maybe [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) (which is written by the highest rep user on so) can help you to write better questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WPF, we set the ComboBox source list of items using `ItemsSource`, not `DataSource`, and it works a little bit differently.

Each item can be any object you'd like to use, keeping in mind that the object itself is your `ValueMember`. In your case, using a dictionary will give, by default, an appearance like "[1, Sunday]" for each item because the item will be of type `KeyValuePair(Of String, String)`.

To style it how you would like, it's easiest to use XAML templates, such as like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding comboSource}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Then, the ComboBox's `SelectedItem` will be the `KeyValuePair`, so just use its `Key` when you need to use the selected item elsewhere as intended.